# Anylogic: Agent Based Parameter Value write out

Tags: database, dataset, output, anylogic

I currently generate about 800-1000 agents, I could like to write out two of parameter values for each agent at the end of simulation.

The parameters are current a setup as below with 218 dimensions list in the Module_List

[image]

Please see the example of how the data would look currently when viewing it per agent

[image]

I would like you to get the data each on following formats or at least any thing.
Option 1:
[image]
Option 2:
[image]

I tried to use the dataset and output tool but I am unable to get to read the parameter as it in inside the agent and not on the main. In my main, I just have a graph that give the total of each agent per state.

[image]